# how would i use fopen() to accept an argument from a function (c programming)

Tags: c, fopen

Example:

```
void readDoc(FILE *doc_file) {
}
```

How can I get `fopen` to read the `doc_file` when the notation requires you to know the document name before hand because in this case the file name is an argument in the `readDoc` function.

Comment: You already have the file handle. You don't need `fopen`.

Comment: Please read some documentation first. E.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: not sure i understand, what do you mean i wont need fopen

Comment: @gensou `fopen()` opens a file and gives you a `FILE*`. In your `readDoc` function, you already have a `FILE*` and thus don't need `fopen()`.

Comment: so if you passed in the argument doc.txt the `readDoc` would open that file?

Comment: No, you need to use fopen() first to get the FILE * of that file. Which in turn, you'd pass to readDoc().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need fopen because fopen is used to open a file and return a FILE* for that file.
In the code you have shared, you seem to already have a FILE* with you as a parameter.
So you just need to use any read (fread,fscanf,fgets etc.) functions to read the file.
However, you need to ensure that fopen is called on the file you need to read and the FILE* which is returned is passed to the readDoc function.

Comment: From his comments it doesn't seem he has the file already open.

Comment: @hesham_EE You are right. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks